# Calling c++ overloaded operator[] after using dynamic instantiation of the containing class doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, dynamic, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I am new to C++ and come from a Java and C# background. I have just wrote some code to get a little bit familiar with exceptions in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


class MyException
{
public:
    MyException(string message)
    {
        this->message = message;
    }

    string& getMessage()
    {
        return this->message;
    }

private:
    string message;
};


class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        v = new string[2];
        v[0] = "wdeed";
        v[1] = "yyyyyyy";
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete[] v;
    }
    string& operator[](int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > 1)
            throw MyException("index out of bound exception");

        return v[index];
    }
private:
    string *v;
};


int main()
{
    int index;

    //first option below is not working
    MyClass *myClass = new MyClass();

    //second option works:
    //MyClass myClass;


    cin >> index;
    cout << endl;

    try
    {
        cout << myClass[index];//this is where the error appears
    }
    catch (MyException& ex)
    {
        cout << ex.getMessage();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Other exception";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The statement "cout << myClass[index];" produces errors

The errors I get only when I use dynamic allocation (MyClass *myClass = new MyClass();) are:

1. no operator "<<" matches these operands operand types are:std::ostream<
2. binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'MyClass' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

How can I fix the code?

Comment: Pointers in C++ are never auto-dereferenced, unlike in Java and C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyClass *myClass` is a pointer to a `MyClass` object. As such, you need to dereference it before using it as a `MyClass`:

```
(*myClass)[index];
```

But really, you don't need to use `new` here at all. `myClass` should just be an automatic object (like your commented-out code) and the internal `std::string` dynamic array should be a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But why doesn't the following snippet generate errors?:     string *v = new string[2];
 v[0] = "wewe";
 cout << v[0];              It seems similar to the issue I had, givet the fact that both myClass and v store Heap memory addresses.

Comment: @Andrei: In that code, `v[0]` is of type `string`, for which the extraction operator (`operator<<`) has been overloaded. In your original code, you have `myClass[index]`, which is of type `MyClass`, for which the extraction operator has not been overloaded. Note that the error you get is about `operator<<`, not `operator[]`. Because `myClass[index]` is still a valid operation, it's just not calling the function you wrote, but just doing plain pointer indexing.